# Google Cloud SQL Migration Job stuck on Running

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I've got a database on Google SQL that is used by our application running on kubernetes in GKE.
The mysql instance is running on 5.6, and I need to update it to 5.7, so I tried using the new migration jobs.

I've set up the connection profile and all the required permissions for the source DB, then followed the instructions to make a continuous migration.

The Job says it's running, migrating the ~450GB database. After about a day, it's still running, the storage used seems to have stopped growing, and the replication delay is at 0. The source database is not currently in use (That's why I'm unsing it to try this out before doing the same with a more important db).

According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/manage-jobs#migration_job_status_and_actions), if the dump phase is done, I should be able to promote the instance, but the promote button remains greyed out, and there's no way to check the running state (it only says "running", and I don't see any way to check if it's dumping, on CDC, or anything else).

The documentation seems a bit lacking, and I couldn't find anything by googling around. Has anyone been using this?

In short, my questions are: 
*Why can't I promote the instance? 

and how can I check in what phase is the migration?*

Here's a screencap of my job:

[link because SO doesn't let me embed images yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk5Xp.png)

Thanks.

p.d.: the tag that the documentation says should be used in stackoverflow is: google-cloud-database-migration-service, which is too long and stackoverflow doesn't allow, so I used google-cloud-sql instead :/

Comment: As of this writing, you seem to be using a feature that is currently [Alpha](https://cloud.google.com/products#product-launch-stages) and that explains the lack of documentation. I suggest contacting [GCP Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) so we can take a look into your project.

Comment: Tank you! Yes, I have sent feedback to them, but it seems the feature still needs some polishing. In the meantime I'll see if I can do the move by hand using a mysql instance in a VM as intermediary.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing an issue like this, but possibly more frustrating. After a week for a 2TB database, storage resets to near-zero and the full dump restarts, without any errors or indication of what happened.